# Opening Website using batch file on remote systems on the network

Tags: batch-file

Request your experience and expertise, I have requirement, where I want to maintain the URL to be opened and hostname or the ipaddress of the system where the website has to be opened.
Could this be done by maintaining details in a batch file and running the same.

Thank you,
Best Regards,

Comment: This question isn't clear.  You want to open a URL on a particular host?  And you want to do it in a batch file?  Or is there something else you want?

Comment: hi, Yes I want to open an URL on a particular host, using a batch file.